# Is light transverse electromagnetic (TEM) or transverse magnetic (TM) wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

My apologies if this is a duplicate. I have been trying to understand the differences between Maxwell's solutions. So far I gathered that TEM requires free current and at least 2 conductors differentially excited. Whilst TM is a wave guide mode which doesn't require free current and hence TM waves can propagate in free space or on surfaces. I find it confusing as I always accepted light is a TEM wave which really no longer fits my understanding. Can you please help clarifying my confusion?

Comment: In my experience, the descriptors TM and TEM have been applied only to waveguides, not to free space.  I may be wrong, but I would say that neither is used to describe free space propagation.

Comment: @garyp so then my question becomes what is the nature of an electromagnetic wave in free space ? What makes a waveguide ? Is it down to the boundary conditions ? If that's the case then free space should be (theoretically) counted as a waveguide too, no ?

Comment: I suppose free space could be considered to be a waveguide.  But no one does. It's perhaps a frustrating fact of physics life that one has to accept the usage of words as they are commonly accepted, even if that usage doesn't quite make sense to you.  Light is a transverse electromagnetic wave, but we don't call it TEM.  The electric field is transverse to the propagation vector, as is the magnetic field vector.  Full stop.

Comment: @garyp some do, a very famous example being L. J. Chu: "Physical Limitations of Omni-Directional Antennas". Near the antenna, the near field, you may have any kinds of components.

Answer (score 3):

Light in free space is a transverse electromagnetic wave, i.e., the oscillating field vectors of the electric and magnetic fields are orthogonal to the wave vector $\vec k$, i.e. transverse to the propagation direction. The acronyms TEM, TM, TE waves refer to the propagation of different modes of electromagnetic waves in waveguides. TEM means that there are only transverse electric and magnetic fields. TM means that there is no longitudinal magnetic field but a longitudinal electric field, TE means that there is no longitudinal electric field. While these waveguide modes usually refer to microwave propagation in metallic or dielectric waveguides, there are also waveguide modes of light waves in fibers with similar characteristics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, TM has a time varying E component in the direction of propagation. However TEM has none, my understanding free current gives the rise for transverse E and M fields. Have I confused myself here ? Also, does the wave equation is independent of the propagation mode (TEM, TM and TE) ?

Comment: user379931 - The wave equation is the same for all electromagnetic waves in a not conductive and not magnetic linear dielectric and contains the light speed in the respective material. Wave solutions in waveguides, however, also have to obey the transverse boundary conditions. This leads to the different propagation modes. With the exception of the TEM mode, which has only transverse electric and magnetic field components, the TE and TM have, in general, also longitudinal electric or magnetic field components

Comment: that's very helpful thank you. What drives the E and M fields of a TEM wave through free space ?

Comment: @user379931 - Electromagnetic waves propagating in free space (which are transverse waves) are the consequence of the mutual interlinkage of free, time varying magnetic and electric  fields as described by Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 0):

**It is TEM wave**
In the space the radiation far field is TEM wave. That means for the far field the electric field and magnetic field are all Transverse.